# After zoom out unable to find the webelement in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my app, I need to zoom out and then find out the web element.
 I zoom out using Robot robot = new Robot(). It zoomed out successfully. After that, it doesn't find the web element. I tried with an explicit wait.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

 Thread.sleep(5000);
 System.out.println("About to zoom out");
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 }



new WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("mpath"))))
            .click();
WebElement module1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("msite")));
    module1.click() ;
```

Comment: Please share Html of element  and stack trace of error.

Comment: I got an error as,"Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector".

Comment: Please share Html of element and check that are you getting correct css locator from properties file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your case exactly, but here's what I would try to do if I were you.

**1. Try to zoom out the browser in a different way.**

Instead of using Robot class, try to use:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "-"))   (Keys.COMMAND on MacOS).
```

You could also try out Actions class if this doesn't work.

**2. Consider looking for that element again, after the resize.**

Not sure how it works during resizing of a page, but I know that after the refresh, WebElement's id might change, which might cause your problem.

Anyway, if none of these work, try to post the error code so we can try to help you.

Comment: I tried the code you mentioned.But it doesn't work.

 `WebElement so = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("site_ov")));
 so.click();
 
 
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 so.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "-"));
  
new WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("mpath"))))
            .click();
WebElement module1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("msite")));
    module1.click();`

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you keep your locator strings in `poperties` file?

Could you please post the error code that you're getting?

Comment: In Selenium, when you locate an element and then page gets reloaded in any way, the webdriver looses reference to that object and it needs to be found again.

Maybe your application is refreshed or reloaded after you first click your so element. If that is the case, you need to locate it again and then perform the sendKeys command. This should work for you